# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds 8 exception on processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm getting an error of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds 8 I'm not sure why- my images start from 0. The line processing seems to be highlighting is            `image(images[ic], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);`
 Any help to resolve this will be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Calendar;
PImage[] images = new PImage[8];
int ic;
PImage img;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);

  for ( int i = 0; i< images.length; i++ )
{
images[i] = loadImage( i + ".png" );   // make sure images "0.jpg" to "11.jpg" exist
}  
}

void draw(){
  ic= 0;
  float tileCountX =10;
  float tileCountY = 10;
  float stepX = width/tileCountX;
  float stepY = height/tileCountY;
  for (float gridY = 0; gridY < height; gridY += stepY){
    for (float gridX = 0; gridX < width; gridX += stepX){
           image(images[ic], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);
           ic++;  
  }
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  if (key=='s' || key=='S') saveFrame(timestamp()+"_##.png");
}

// timestamp
String timestamp() {
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  return String.format("%1$ty%1$tm%1$td_%1$tH%1$tM%1$tS", now);
}
```

Comment: Please post complete code sample that at the least is compilable.

Comment: What are the values of height and width? the ic index in the draw() function may be growing beyond 7 causing the exception. Of couse a stacktrace and complete code would help.

Comment: Your comment `make sure images "0.jpg" to "11.jpg" exist` implies that your pImage is too small.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to processing that is my complete code...

Comment: Post the complete stack trace and highlight the line in your code where the index out of bounds occurs

Answer (score 1):

Look at this block of code:

```
  ic= 0;
  float tileCountX =10;
  float tileCountY = 10;
  float stepX = width/tileCountX;
  float stepY = height/tileCountY;
  for (float gridY = 0; gridY < height; gridY += stepY){
    for (float gridX = 0; gridX < width; gridX += stepX){
           image(images[ic], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);
           ic++;  
     }
   }
```

Your width and height are 500, so that inner loop is going to execute 500 times. You're incrementing ic each time.

You're using that ic variable to index into your array- but your array only has 8 indexes, not 500. That's what's causing your error.

You need to take a step back and try to figure out exactly what you're trying to do, as this code doesn't make a ton of sense.